# Django crontab is not running, even i setup everything

Tags: python, cron, python3, django

I am using crontab in django and my OS is ubuntu

```
def my_scheduled_job():
    print("1")
```

This is code in settings.py

```
CRONJOBS = [
    ('*/1 * * * *', 'stocks.cron.my_scheduled_job')
]
```

If I run

> python3 manage.py crontab run #with hash

it runs the function and print it, but it does not run when I run server. What should I do.

It was my code in crontab

```
    crontab -e
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/stockstelegraph/manage.py crontab run 6b918d2422a9f4fce735a3383cee6485 # django-cronjobs
```

Comment: Are you sure your job is not running? A job run by cron will not print to your screen. You can direct the output to a file and then view the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code actually works. You may be think that `print("1")` should appear in stdout? So it doesn't work that way, because cron doesn't use `stdour` and `stderr` for it's output. To see actual results you should point path to some log file in `CRONJOBS` list: just put `'>> /path/to/log/file.log'` as last argument, e.g:

```
('*/1 * * * *', 'stocks.cron.my_scheduled_job', '>> /path/to/log/file.log')
```